# Node 'request' module: Getting hold of the last response in a 302-redirect

Tags: node.js, http, redirect, request

I am using the Node `request` module from inside the Node shell to submit a login form via an HTTP POST. If the login is successful, the server redirects to a 'home' page (with an HTTP GET).

The documentation for `request` says that any and all redirects happen by default, and this indeed *is* happening - I can see the redirect on the server side.

However, on the client side, I need to be able to get hold of the (html) response body of the final redirection that happened on the server side. (In my case, there is only 1 redirect to a home page but it obviously could be more than 1 redirects also in the general case.)

Here's my client-side code:

```
var request = require('request');
request.post('http://localhost:8080/login', { 
    form: {
        user:'u',
        password:'p'
    }}, 
    function(err, resp, body) { 
        console.log(body); 
});
```

The problem is: The above code prints nothing on the console!

**Question:** How to print the final response? Additionally, in case of a chain of redirects, is it possible to get, on the client side, some info at least on the intermediate redirects - eg, at minimum their URLs but ideally their URLs along with their HTTP Method types, request query parameters, and request bodies?

Nothing is wrong on the server, because: If I use `curl` against the  server, I see the html of the final home page just fine:

```
$ curl -L -d 'user=u' -d 'password=p' http://localhost:8080/login
<html> ... </html>
$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var request = require('request').defaults({
  followRedirect: true,
  followAllRedirects: true
});

request.post('http://localhost:8080/login', { 
    form: {
        user:'u',
        password:'p'
    }}, 
    function(err, resp, body) { 
        console.log(body); 
});
```

Try that, the difference is the two options. followRedirect should be true by default. Also, take a look at what is actually being returned, I had a similar problem until I realized the redirect was happening in the HTML and not from the server.